# unable to convert from 'page' to 'Xamarin.Forms.Page'

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, navigation

I want to navigate to other page in Xamarin Forms but it is not working.
my code is:

```
private async void btnlogin_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { await Navigation.PushAsync(new CreateExpense());}
```

the error is:

> unable to convert from 'page' to 'Xamarin.Forms.Page'. by the way the
>   'page' is in contentView.

Comment: cannot navigation ContentView, page must be Content Page

Answer (score 1):

you can not navigate to content view so `CreateExpense` should be using `Xamarin.Forms` and should Inherit `ContentPage`, so you should do some thing like below on `CreateExpense`

```
using Xamarin.Forms;

class CreateExpense : ContentPage
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason it is not working is that you can only push in your Navigation Stack any classes that inherit from the `Xamarin.Forms.Page` class for eg `ContentPage`

ContentView, on the other hand, is a `Xamarin.Forms.View` and not a Page to make this work you can do two thing

- Convert your ContentView to a ContentPage.
- Make a ContentPage hold your ContentView.(Reusability) more information here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/contentview'